# Magento: There has been an error processing your request

Tags: php, magento

After installing a few themes and working with them, I'm getting an error every time I try to lead a product page:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number: (long string of numbers)

I have found an tried a couple guides on troubleshooting this. Firstly, I have followed the steps in this article: http://kb.magenting.com/content/24/37/en/magento-there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request.html

1) I have flushed the cache

2) Magento compiler is disabled

3) I do not have any modules installed

4) I switched themes and flushed cache

...None of the above solved the problem.

---

The next thing I did was follow the steps in these articles:

http://yohanes.pradono.com/2013/09/16/magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/magento-install-error-exception-printing-is-disabled

which was:

1) changed app/etc/local.xml.sample to app/etc/local.xml

2) I went to magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and changed:

```
protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => null,
```

to

```
protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

3) And then created tmp folder in the root directory. The error page now has many lines of error text instead of just a log number, but still no fix.

The error page now displays:

```
 Invalid method OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::renderCloudOptions(Array
 (
 )
 )

 Trace:
 #0     C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\magic\catalog\product\view\media.phtml(32): Varien_Object->__call('renderCloudOpti...', Array)
```

...and so on up to #33

Anyone have any suggestions? I am willing to jump hoops if necessary. I've spent quite a few hours on my site, so any help I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

To see the exact exception message you may need to rename the file `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` which you may find at

> app/etc/local.xml.sample

Comment: forgot to mention, i did do that

Comment: Leaving this active on a live e-commerce server breaks PCI-DSS as it exposes stack-trace contents to anyone probing the website.